# Rails app - jquery broken on production, fine on dev. Sprockets error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a small Rails app that is working fine in my local development environment.  I have had some work done by a freelancer which works fine locally, but seems to have caused numerous problems on my production server.

There were a whole load of Gem problems (mainly around therubyracer and libv8) which prevented the application from starting.  I fixed by trial and error with the Gemfile, and I've been able to start the app.

Now, although the app starts, jQuery is not working at all and I'm seeing the following error in my browser:

```
Uncaught Error: Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'jquery-fileupload/basic'
(in /home/pastonpaper/pastpaper/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:19) application.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined www.pastonpaper.com:19
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

I've no idea how to troubleshoot this - could anyone give me some pointers? As I say, it all works fine in my separate dev environment.

Comment: Have you run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`  on your server after fixing your problems ? Do you have the gem `jquery-rails`, or the jquery file in `app/assets/javascripts/` ?

Comment: Stackoverflow does it again!  I sat up for two hours stressing over this last night, and you fixed it with one command!  I've so much to learn...To answer the questions specifically, I did have the jquery-rails gem.  It was the bundle command that fixed it.  Thanks very much.

Comment: You're welcome. What are you using to deploy your application ?

Comment: Passenger I think.  I didn't set up the production environment - all I know is that it gives me a minor heart attack whenever I so much as look at it...I guess Capistrano would be an improvement when I can steel myself up to install it.

Comment: Yep, I recommand you to use capistrano. It is really easy to install and use, and also provides you a way to execute your assets procompile everytime you deploy. :)

Comment: I will take your advice on this and get this done - hopefully it will make my Rails life less stressful!

Answer (score 1):

Just include this line in production.rb file under config directory and it will work fine.

```
config.assets.debug = true
```